# Boost converter - Different value for change in duty cycle causing oscillations and sub-optimal performance

Tags: power-electronics, boost, simulink, mppt

I'm trying to simulate an MPPT system in Simulink. The algorithm is working fine in hardware, but when I'm simulating on Simulink I have an issue.

When I change the value of delta duty_cycle (i.e. the change in duty cycle), the tracker starts to oscillate. It does extract optimal output for a particular range of ideal power, but oscillates or extracts half the power for other ranges.

I believe this is a problem with my boost converter. In my real hardware I'm using a flyback converter.

Model:
[image: System Model]

Boost converter:
[image: Boost Convertor]

Perturb and observe output:
[image: Perturb and Observe Output]

Incremental conductance output: (1e-04)
[image: Incremental Conductance Output (1e-04)]

Incremental conductance output (250e-04)
[image: Incremental Conductance Output (250e-04)]

[Simulink model link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1koSP09V2NEwhtjKcylD0zoSZ1WieEMWg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you please shed more details on the control loop? The dynamics of a boost converter is different than that of a flyback.

Comment: @VerbalKint, I don't know much about boost convertor or control loop. I refereed the couple of articles and text book. The general theme of the circuit is that the output of P&O or I&C algorithm control the duty cycle.

Comment: The thing is if you replace a working circuit featuring a flyback converter by the same circuit now involving a boost converter, and nothing changed in the control strategy, I am not surprised it does not work : ) The control-to-output transfer function of the boost converter features a right-half-pane zero (as the flyback) and makes it a non-minimum-phase transfer function more difficult to stabilize that the loop of a buck converter for instance.